# Почему происходит android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

Почему происходит exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` при попытке прочитать файл с интернета?

```java
URL fileUrl = new URL("*********");
         InputStream imageStream = fileUrl.openStream();
         System.out.println(imageStream.read());
```

Comment: В Android запрещено обращаться в сеть с главного потока (он же UI Thread)

Comment: @IR42 можете пож показать пример как надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя обращаться к сети с главного потока, так как это действие, требующее временных затрат, иногда больших, что приводит к зависанию приложения, создайте для этого специальный класс, например, так (это код для получения html кода какой-либо страницы):

```
private static class DownloadContentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                return result.toString();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (urlConnection != null)
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: было бы хорошо, если бы вы привели [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) использования класса